# Websphere MQ Cluster Workload Balancing: messages going to dead letter queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I have created a WMQ cluster with 3 QMgrs. 2 Full repository and 1 partial repository. Here is the `mqsc` used:

```
crtmqm GW
strmqm GW
runmqsc GW
alter qmgr deadq('SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE')
define listener(gw.listener) trptype(TCP) port(1416) ipaddr(xx.xx.xx.xx)
start listener(gw.listener)
define channel(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN) chltype(svrconn)
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
end

runmqsc QM01
alter qmgr repos('DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER')
end

runmqsc QM02
alter qmgr repos('DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER')
end

runmqsc QM01
define chl(to.QM01) chltype(clusrcvr) trptype(tcp) +
       conname('xx.xx.xx.xx(1414)') cluster(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER) 
end

runmqsc QM02
define chl(to.QM02) chltype(clusrcvr) trptype(tcp) +
       conname('xx.xx.xx.xx(1415)') cluster(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER) 
end

runmqsc GW
define chl(to.GW) chltype(clusrcvr) trptype(tcp) +
       conname('xx.xx.xx.xx(1416)') cluster(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER) 
end

runmqsc QM01
DEFINE CHANNEL(TO.QM02) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) +
       CONNAME('xx.xx.xx.xx(1415)') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
end

runmqsc QM02
DEFINE CHANNEL(TO.QM01) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) +
       CONNAME('xx.xx.xx.xx(1414)') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
end

runmqsc GW
DEFINE CHANNEL(TO.QM01) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) +
       CONNAME('xx.xx.xx.xx(1414)') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
DEFINE CHANNEL(TO.QM02) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) +
       CONNAME('xx.xx.xx.xx(1415)') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
end

runmqsc QM02
define qlocal('BACKUP') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
define qlocal('PROVIDER') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
define qlocal('RESPONSE') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
define qlocal('STORE') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
REFRESH CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER) REPOS(YES) 
end

runmqsc QM01
define qlocal('BACKUP') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
define qlocal('PROVIDER') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
define qlocal('RESPONSE') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
define qlocal('STORE') CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER)
REFRESH CLUSTER(DEVELOPMENT.CLUSTER) REPOS(YES)
end
```

Now I am putting a message to QMgr `GW` on queue `PROVIDER`. Please note that `GW` does not host this queue. It is hosted by `QM01` and `QM02`

```
amqsput PROVIDER GW
```

Sadly all the messages are going to dead letter queue of the QMgr `GW`.

Kindly help to fix this. Any suggestions for debugging will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible issues here.

The channels are not identically defined.  Some have mixed-case names, others have all uppercase names.  This *may* work if you are counting on the lack of quotes to ensure they are all folded to upper case by the QMgr.  However, the commands have obviously been edited, at least so far as the `CONNAME` values are concerned, so I'm not assuming that the resulting objects match.

After creating the cluster, did you check that all channels show as `AUTO-EXPLICIT`?  This is how you know the cluster was properly booted up.

It's also possible that the `REFRESH CLUSTER` command is causing the outage.  This is not required when defining new objects, and in fact is quite disruptive.  It waits on the channels to restart and at the point in time that you are running the command, the commands to advertise the new objects have been sent to the repositories but not returned.  The `REFRESH CLUSTER` then requests the channels to stop, possibly in mid-batch, queues up commands for the cluster to delete the information it just received but has not yet replied to, and then sends new commands to the cluster advertising the objects it just deleted.  If this sounds confusing, think how the cluster command server on the repository feels.

Remove the `REFRESH CLUSTER` command from the queue definition script.

Once you ascertain that the channels have all advanced to `AUTO-EXPLICIT` and removed the `REFRESH CLUSTER` you can start the actual debugging.  It really helps in these cases to look at the DLQ header of the dead messages to find out what reason code is listed.  This usually provides sufficient information to find the problem.  You can also enable a variety of QMgr diagnostic events and view them using one of the event viewing tools, or look at the error logs on the QMgrs at either end of the channel.

---

These next suggestions have nothing to do with your diagnostic, other than a QMgr built using Best Practices will in general be less error prone and easier to debug.  Here then are some unsolicited MQ Cluster Best Practice recommendations.

- Abandon the `TO.[QMGR]` channel names! Use `[cluster].[qmgr]` names instead, for example `DEVCLUS.QM01`.  This ensures that you will always have channels dedicated to each cluster, even if you have overlapping clusters.  It does, however, mean cluster names can't have a `.` in them and must be < 10 characters.
- On things that are not full repositories, define an explicit `CLUSSDR` to only one of the repositories.  Should you ever have more than two repositories (for example during a migration) the cluster members will be able to find it this way.
- Always use quotes in your definitions.  If you are having problems getting something to work then definitions that have only one possible interpretation are a shorter path to resolution.
- Give the channels time to settle when defining a new cluster channel, and verify that it starts and goes to the correct state.
- Use `AMQSPUT` to open newly defined remotely-hosted cluster queues for output, but without actually putting messages to them.  Make sure you get no errors (i.e. the queues resolve) during the open and then make sure the cluster channels are up.  ***Then*** execute `amqsput` and send messages.
- `REFRESH CLUSTER` is a command to be used on partial repositories whereas `RESET CLUSTER` is the command to be used on full repositories.  In this case the command is being used improperly and on the wrong type of cluster node.  Expect problems.
- Hopefully in real life there are no application queues hosted on full repository QMgrs.  The best possible thing you can do for your cluster is to host the full repositories on dedicated QMgrs - even if those are extra QMgrs on the same host as the application QMgrs.  Separating these ensures that cluster operation traffic and application traffic never traverse the same channels.  It also makes it possible to patch or upgrade the repositories before the application QMgrs.